# Custom validator with master page button click

Tags: asp.net, validation, master-pages, customvalidator

i have a custom validator in a content page

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
   OnServerValidate="RevisionValidate" 
   ControlToValidate="TextBoxRevisionOrder" 
   ErrorMessage="Invalid RevOrder Format">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

where RevisionValidate is a serverside method

```
protected void RevisionValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
               //Code goes here           
             if (CurrentRevisionOrder != "-1" && ChangedRevisionOrder == "-1")
                            {
                                val = "Not Valid";


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                val = "Valid";

                            }
                            args.IsValid = (val == "Valid");
                        }
```

Custom validator fires perfectly on content page button click but the issue is i also have a button in the master page which the custom validator need to fire.with my current code it's not firing on master page button click.any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to check

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ValidationGroup` property on button in master page.

Content Page:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="TextBoxRevisionOrder" runat="server"/>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
   OnServerValidate="RevisionValidate" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBoxRevisionOrder" 
          ErrorMessage="Invalid RevOrder Format" ValidationGroup="Revision">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Master Page:

```
<asp:Button Id="MasterButton" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Revision"> Click
</asp:Button>
```